# How do you call a loop that has already ended?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x=0
while x<=10:
    x+=1
```

Once `x` gets to ten, is there a way to restart the loop so that x goes to 0 again then adds until 10?

Comment: Wrap it in another loop?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  There's lots of ways to reuse code, the best one is going to depend on the purpose.

Comment: Please explain the real problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: put the code in a function and call it when you want to it again.

Comment: Yeah, that works, thank you!

Comment: You don't "call" a loop... you *could* call a method or function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the code in a function and call it when you want to it again.

```
def count():
    x=0
    while x<10:
        x+=1
        print(x)

count() # run loop once
count() # run loop again
```

gives you:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 0):

In this way you can loop it forever:

```
while True:
    x=0
    while x<=10:
        x+=1
```

---

And if you want to stop the loop you can use `break` like this:

```
while True:
    x=0
    while x<=10:
        x+=1
    break
```

But I think what you want is a neat function like this:

```
def loop_n_times(n):
    loop = 0
    while loop < n:
        x = 0
        while x <= 10:
            x += 1
        loop += 1
```

With this function you can call the loop as many times as you like by simply writing: `loop_n_times(n)` and `n` is the number of loops you want it to make.

Example:
loop_n_times(3) will do the loop 3 times.

Comment: But then you need to show how to break out of that `while True`